# Memory leak in C, most likely due to realloc

Tags: c, memory-leaks, realloc

I have a program that is supposed to receive input, remember the longest string and print it out at EOF. My code works, but when run through a debugger there is a memory leak detected. I am compiling in Windows and do not have a proper debugger like Valgrind so I do not get much information about the error. The only thing I can imagine can cause this leak is the realloc() or free() function. However, I am not skilled enough in C to understand what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p;
    char *line;
    int sc;
    p = (char*) malloc ( sizeof(char) );
    line = (char*) malloc ( sizeof(char) );
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    p[count] = 0;
    while ( ( sc = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        if ( p == NULL ) {
            p = (char*) realloc ( p, sizeof(char) );
        }
        if ( isalpha(sc) ) {
            p[count] = sc;
            count++;
            p = (char*) realloc( p, (count+1)*sizeof(char) );
            p[count] = 0;
        } else if ( sc == '\n' || sc == ' ' ) {
            if ( count > max ) {
                line = (char*) realloc( line, (count+1)*sizeof(char) );
                strcpy( line, p );
                max = count;
            } else if ( count == 0) {
                printf("%d characters in longest word: %s\n", max, line);
                free(line);
                free(p);
                break;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O! This isn't really a [mcve]; try to make it one!

Comment: Why are you casting malloc in c?

Comment: There is a memory leak because `free(line);` and `free(p);` are not called in all control paths.

Comment: hint: use something like `unsigned newsize=5*oldsize/4+10;` before `realloc` instead of `count+1` and remember the size separately from the `count`

Comment: Tip: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.

Comment: ... more robust to use `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` (example for first usage).

Comment: Note also that `free()`ing a pointer does not change its value, and in particular, does not assign `NULL` to it.  It retains its original value, but that value is no longer a valid pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: right, but there is a `break` after the `free`s, directing the control to `return 0`; so it should not matter here.

Comment: @Slayahh, how did you know that there is memory leak in your program?

Comment: @Abhijit We have an automated grader that runs tests on our programs and sends us an email with the error if it's faulty.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have tried moving both free() to the end of the program (right above return(0)) but that does not work either, surely that would cover all the cases?

Comment: @Slayahh, as you did not assign NULL to both 'p' and 'line' your tool is considering it as memory leak. Assign NULL to both and check. Also see my answer below.

Comment: @Abhijit Where exactly you mean -->> `as you did not assign NULL to both 'p' and 'line' `. Where should that happen?

Comment: @Michi both that statement should be after `free(line);` and `free(p);`

Comment: @Slayahh Try my code and tell me if your problem persists.

Comment: @Abhijit Please check my Updated Answer and see why I'm not agree

Comment: @Abhijit I never said that is a memory leak (and there is not) , I do now say that is about an uninitialised value :)

Comment: This is not at all memory leak. While you use `alloc`  it initialized each field with the value provided. In this case after `malloc` if you use `memset` you will get the same result but that does not mean `memset` stops the memory leak. You are using a tool and it has its own algorithm and we can not just blindly trust the report it gives.

Comment: This is my last comment. this line `line = (char*) malloc ( sizeof(char) );` only needs `calloc` Try to debug it and you'll see. Have a good day

Comment: You never call `free` in the case of `getchar()` returning `EOF`. It would be better to have the free statements after the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695254/memory-leak-in-c-most-likely-due-to-realloc#comment80339024_46695254) that you "have tried moving both `free()` to the end of the program", but I don't believe you. The problem appears to be that this is a badly designed program which does not always reach the `free()` statements because when `sc` is a space or newline, `count` is unlikely to be 0, and after `count` is reset to 0, the next character is read into `sc` (unlikely to be a space or newline).

Simply moving the calls to `free()` to the end of the program fixes the memory leak, which was reported by Valgrind:

```
λ> valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out
==2967== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2967== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2967== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2967== Command: ./a.out
==2967== 
this is a test
==2967== 
==2967== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2967==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 2 blocks
==2967==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 12 frees, 42 bytes allocated
==2967== 
==2967== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2967==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 2 blocks
==2967==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2967==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2967==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2967==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2967== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2967== 
==2967== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2967== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But there are many other issues with the code. First, never store the result of a call to `realloc()` in the only copy of a pointer you have to the memory being reallocated; a null pointer may be returned, and if so you then have a memory leak and lost data. Instead, use a temporary variable to hold the result, and assign this value to the original pointer only after checking for a null pointer. If a null pointer has been returned, the simplest solution is probably to terminate the program with an error message, as is done below; the error could be handled in other ways, so long as it is handled.

The posted code is more complex than it needs to be, with multiple calls to `malloc()` and `realloc()`. Instead, initialize `p` and `line` to `NULL`, and reallocate only as needed. There is no need to begin by allocating space for 1 `char`; this can be done when the first character needs to be stored. Also, there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C (a different story in C++); and, `sizeof char` is always 1, so this is redundant and only clutters the code.

The fundamental problem in the posted code seems to be that when a character is read, `count` is incremented. Then if this character is a space or a newline, `count` may not be 0, so the exit with deallocation condition may not be met. Instead of complicated conditions, rethink the flow of the program.

After reading a character (unless `EOF` is encountered), if that character is alphabetic, `count` should be incremented, and `p` should be reallocated. If this step is successful, the character should be stored in `p[]`, which should then be null-terminated.

Otherwise, if the character is a `\n` or a space, `max` should be compared with `count`. If `count` is larger, then `line` should be reallocated. If this step is successful, the string pointed to by `p` should be copied to `line[]`. Then `max` is given the value of `count`, and `count` is reset to 0.

After the loop has terminated, the results are printed only if there were words in the input. Then deallocation can occur before the program terminates.

The `isalpha()` function and similar functions from `ctype.h` expect an `int` value in the range of an `unsigned char` (or `EOF`). Often you need to cast the value of arguments to these functions to `unsigned char` to avoid undefined behavior. But, in this case the cast is unnecessary since `getchar()` returns an `int` value in the range of an `unsigned char` (or `EOF`).

You might also consider using the `isspace()` function instead of `sc == '\n' || sc == ' '`. This would allow other whitespace characters, such as `'\t'`, to separate words in the input. As written in the OP, an input of `"one\tword"` (where `'\t'` is a tab character) would result in an output of:

```
7 characters in longest word: oneword
```

Here is a modified version of the posted code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    int sc;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while ((sc = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(sc)) {
            ++count;                                    // read a letter
            char *temp = realloc(p, count + 1);         // +1 for '\0'
            if (temp == NULL) {                         // check allocation
                perror("Failure to reallocate p");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            p = temp;                                   // OK to reassign p
            p[count-1] = sc;                            // store character
            p[count] = 0;                               // add null-terminator
        } else if (isspace(sc)) {
            if (count > max) {
                char *temp = realloc(line, count + 1);  // +1 for '\0'
                if (temp == NULL) {                     // check allocation
                    perror("Failure to reallocate line");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                line = temp;                            // OK to reassign line
                strcpy(line, p);
                max = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    if (max > 0) {
        printf("%d characters in longest word: %s\n", max, line);        
    } else {
        puts("No words in input");
    }

    free(line);
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a clean bill of health from Valgrind:

```
λ> valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out
==4753== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4753== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4753== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4753== Command: ./a.out
==4753== 
this is a   testrun
7 characters in longest word: testrun
==4753== 
==4753== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4753==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4753==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 16 frees, 69 bytes allocated
==4753== 
==4753== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4753== 
==4753== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4753== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think during debugging after the `free()` function call; you checked the value of the  pointer `p` and `line`, and you still see the value(string) it is pointing to. If so that is not memory leak because `free()` does not change the value of pointer or assign `0` or `'\0'` character in it. `free()` just free the block of memory so that next time when you call any memory allocation function it will get that memory as available memory, and allocate it. Therefore after calling `free()`, we always assign `NULL` to the pointer like `p = NULL;`.

Correct the code as below and try:-

```
free(line);
free(p);
line = NULL;
p = NULL;
break;
```

Comment: `Not sure but I think ` This is definitely a kind of an Answer which should not be given.

Comment: My not sure is about his testing not about my answer

Comment: Please explain with a working code your suggestions from your Answer.

Comment: @Michi please see my updated answer. Also I see your answer, can you please explain why its give memory leak while we use `malloc` but not with `alloc`. Thanking in advance

Comment: It is not necessary to set `line` and `p` to `NULL` after the calls to `free()`; it is even debatable whether this is a good practice in general. But how does this solve OP's problem, anyway? After making the suggested changes, OP code has exactly the same behavior as before.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your coding approach I'll use `calloc` (you need) instead of `malloc` to get rid of that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    int sc;
    p = calloc ( sizeof(char), 1);
    line = calloc ( sizeof(char),1 );
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t max = 0;
    p[count] = 0;
    while ( ( sc = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        if ( p == NULL ) {
            p = realloc ( p, sizeof(char) );
        }
        if ( isalpha(sc) ) {
            p[count] = (char)sc;
            count++;
            p = realloc( p, (count+1) * sizeof(char) );
            p[count] = 0;
        } else if ( sc == '\n' || sc == ' ' ) {
            if ( count > max ) {
                line = realloc( line, (count+1)*sizeof(char) );
                strcpy( line, p );
                max = count;
            } else if ( count == 0) {
                printf("%zu characters in longest word: %s\n", max, line);
                free(line);
                free(p);
                break;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output with Valgrind:

```
==4362== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4362== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4362== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4362== Command: ./program
==4362== 
Hello World

5 characters in longest word: Hello
==4362== 
==4362== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4362==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4362==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 2,096 bytes allocated
==4362== 
==4362== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4362== 
==4362== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4362== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Now try to understand, why is not working with `malloc` and why is working with `calloc`.

**EDIT**

Are you sure that is all about a leak? and is not about an uninitialised value?
I'm saying because if you type a letter works fine, the problem comes with Numbers, hence the `calloc` sugestion.

This is the Output of `Valgrind` using your code with no modification:

```
==5042== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5042== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5042== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5042== Command: ./program
==5042== 
1   
==5042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5042==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==5042==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==5042==    by 0x40082B: main (in /home/michael/program)
==5042==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5042==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5042==    by 0x400715: main (in /home/michael/program)
==5042== 
0 characters in longest word: 
==5042== 
==5042== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5042==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5042==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,050 bytes allocated
==5042== 
==5042== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5042== 
==5042== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5042== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't print out the longest word at EOF. It's just a blank line (\n)

Comment: This is not my code (it’s yours) and this is not your Question too. I only fixed some conversion problems, but this doesn’t affect your original code. The reason why I replaced malloc with calloc has nothing to do with your written Algorithm. If you believe that your code doesn’t produce your expected Output, then you should open another Question for that.

Comment: What is gained by using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` here, since `realloc()` is used anyway? Note that the memory leak has not been fixed; if `EOF` is encountered before a newline, the section of code containing the calls to `free()` is never entered. Test by entering "Hello World" and pressing ENTER and then signalling end-of-file from the keyboard. This only appears to work when input is terminated by pressing ENTER twice. This is exactly the same behavior exhibited by OP code....